# Bind port on external ip

Tags: serial-port, bind, netstat

I would like to bind my 3306 port on 0.0.0.0. Actually when I do :

```
netstat -an | grep 3306
```

It returns :

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `/etc/mysql/my.conf` file (prior to 16.04) or `/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf` (from 16.04 on), look for the line `bind-address`.  By default it will be set to `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`.   Just put that line in comment (add a `#` in front of the line).